# ANTLR: get error line number when parsing a multi-line text

Tags: antlr, antlr3

I have the following C function to catch recognition errors thrown by ANTLR:

```
void recognition(pANTLR3_BASE_RECOGNIZER recognizer, pANTLR3_UINT8 *list)
{
    pANTLR3_PARSER parser;
    pANTLR3_EXCEPTION exception;


    parser = (pANTLR3_PARSER) (recognizer->super);
    exception = recognizer->state->exception;

    printf("%d\n", exception->line);   // ALWAYS PRINTS 1 (WHICH IS WRONG)
}
```

If one parses (with ANTLR) a multi-line text that has a typo in the first line, the `recognition` function will print "1" (which is correct). However, if the typo occurs after the first line (i.e. >= 2), the `recognition` function always prints "1" (which is wrong).

The question is: how can one print the correct line number where the parsing error is (suggestion: do I have to update the grammar to increment a specific ANTLR counter every time that it parses a new-line token)?

Comment: Debug the parser to see what is happening. The line info is usually taken from the token that caused the parse error. Is it the token you expected? Does it have correct line info?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible cause is your perception of where the problem is might be different from the parser's - consider this grammar:

```
start : rule1 | rule2;
rule1 : 'A' 'B';
rule2 : 'A' 'C';
```

and input:

```
A
A
```

From our point of view, it might seem that the problem is on line 2 since `A` on first line is correct for both alternatives. But the parser needs to decide which alternative to choose already on the first line, and if neither alternative matches, `NoViableAlt` exception will be thrown at that point in the input - which is still on line 1.

Left-factoring the grammar might help:

```
start : 'A' ( rule1 | rule2 );
rule1 : 'B';
rule2 : 'C';
```

Now, 'A' will be matched and only then the `NoViableAlt` exception will be thrown for input at second line.